# Работа с ComboBox в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Как сделать чтобы пользователь выбирал одно значение, а подставлялось другое. Например, пользователь выбирает название продукта, а в значение (`SelectedValue`) передается его ID?

Comment: А почему бы не сделать преобразование на уровне Viewmodel?

Comment: Можно поподробнее об этом?

Comment: MVVM пользуетесь? Заводите два свойства: `selected product name` и `selected product id`, подписываетесь на изменения, при изменении одного из них меняете и другой.

Comment: Не пользуюсь

Comment: Тогда сделайте `class Product`, добавьте в него property (не поля!) `public string Name` и `public int Id`, и используйте в комбобоксе `DisplayMemberPath`.

Answer (score 1):

Как правильно написали в комментарии, используйте [DisplayMemberPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460612/wpf-combobox-displaymemberpath) для отображения имени, `SelectedValuePath` укажите "ID" и тогда вызвав SelectedValue получите значение соответствующего свойства.
А вообще это как бы можно было узнать [Из мануала](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx), или [погуглив](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath)

Comment: SO рассчитан в первую очередь на новичков. не стоит удивляться, что 80% вопросов здесь можно решить просто погуглив

Comment: @PashaPash я понимаю, но все же во [вводном туре по сайту](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) есть пункт _Don't ask about questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)_ а в [официальной справке](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) в первом же абзаце написано _Прежде чем задать вопрос, убедитесь, что вы выполнили тщательный поиск ответа._
И, в конце концов не вижу не чего плохо еще раз напомнить челвоеку, о пользе поисковиков, особенно учитывая тот факт, что ответ находится по первой же выданной ссылке гугла

Comment: по первой ссылке написано show your work, а не "google first!". по второй  - тщательный поиск ответа - это линк на страницу поиска по сайту - и он призывает не постить дубликаты. а вовсе не посылает в гугл. цель SO - чтобы по той самой первой ссылке из гугла стоял полноценный ответ на самом SO, причем для ruSO - ответ на русском. на первом месте в гугле - очень хорошо расписанный ответ на enSO - и он там только потому, что Chris Anderson не послал топикастера [к манулу](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB&tbm=isch), а сел и написал развернутый ответ.

Comment: @PashaPash В некоторым смысле Вы правы. Просто для меня _show your work_ это вопрос вида: _Вот я у меня следующая проблема `X` я почитал в официальной документации(ссылка) там написано что ее надо решать используя `Y`, а вот теме(ссылка) описывают ее решение используя `Z`, так как же правильнее? или Но у меня не тот ни другой вариант не подходит, есть другие варианты?_ Поэтому я и позволил упомянуть про мануал и гугл. По другим вопросам не хочу разводить полемику.